# 2D Coordinate - Given two lines and their angles, compute the point in which the perpendicular foot length becomes h

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image]

I am given values of $x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2$, $\theta_{1}$, $\theta_{2}$, and $h$.

I want to find out the coordinate of the `Unknown Point of Interest`.

The `Unknown Point of Interest` is the point in which the length of the perpendicular foot between the two blue lines with $\theta_{1}$ becomes $h$. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use trigonometry. If you know $h$ and the angle $\theta_1$, then you can treat the triangle as a right angled triangle and the length of the hypotenuse as $\frac{h}{\sin\theta_1}=h_1$. Then the point of interest can be written as $\{h_1\cos(\theta_1+\theta_2),h_1\sin(\theta_1+\theta_2)\}$ using the same trigonometric argument/transformation from polar co-ordinates to Cartesian.